# ArrayList out of bounds while searching for primal number

Tags: java

I don't get how can it be out of bounds if I bound `i` by the array size. I get `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 116, Size: 116`

`eratosthenes(ArrayList <Integer> array)` checks for primal every element and deletes it if true, then the process is repeated for the next remained element.

```
package arrays;
import java.util.*;

public class Examples {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList <Integer> array = getFilledArrayList(2, 1000);
        eratosthenes(array);
        System.out.println(array.toString());


    }


    private static void eratosthenes(ArrayList <Integer> array) {       
        int index = 0;
        int primal = array.get(index);
        while (index < array.size() - 1) {

            for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {

                if (array.get(i) % primal == 0) array.remove(i);
            }
            index++;
            primal = array.get(index);
        }

    }

    private static ArrayList <Integer> getFilledArrayList(int start, int stop) {
        ArrayList <Integer> array = new ArrayList();
        for (int i = start; i < stop + 1; i++) {
            array.add(i);
        }
        return array;
    }

}
```

Comment: the for loop can remove elements from the list to the point where index < array.size() - 1 is false inside the while and your index becomes greater than your array.size(). or in this case, it's equal to it and throws the exception

Comment: Add another check before you try to increase the index like this  

    if(index + 1 < array.size()){
       primal = array.get(++index);} 

That way you verify that you can find the next primal without throwing an index out of bounds exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array bounds are 0-indexed, meaning that the first element in an array is found at index 0. Therefore, the last index that is within the bounds of an array is the array size minus 1. Thus, the bounds of an array in Java span from `[0, length - 1]`, or stated another way, `[0, length)`.

The culprit is the following snippet:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {

    if (array.get(i) % primal == 0) array.remove(i);
}
index++;
primal = array.get(index);
```

If `array.remove(i)` is called within the loop, the number of values in `array` is reduced. Paired with the increment of `index` in the `index++` line, this may push `index` beyond the bounds of `array` causing an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

For example, if `array` has a length of `1000` and `index` has a value of `998`, calling `array.remove(i)` causes the length of `array` to be reduced to `999`. The increment of `index` causes `index` to have a value of `999`, which is equal to the length of `array`, resulting in an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Answer (score -1):

array.size() -1, since the array index starts at zero